# How to update PADB Paraccel Postgres 8.0.1 stv_partitions failed status after disk change

Tags: paraccel

I have been receiving Disk Full errors in my Postgres 8.0.1 cluster.

While troubleshooting, I ran:

```
select failed, mount point, diskno from stv_partitions;
```

One node had a failed RAID 0 drive a while ago, but has been replaced and that drive has been partitioned and shows good.

How do I update the status from failed=1 (failed) to failed=0 (good) in my postgres cluster?

Thank you!

Comment: `stv_partitions` is **not**  a Postgres table or view. You must be using something else. What does `select version();` show you?

Comment: select version(); returns: the following PostgreSQL 8.0.2 on i686-pc-linux-gnu PADB 5.1.2.0 71826 -- Thank you for your time!

Comment: that can't be, Postgres never had a table like that. It must be some fork of Postgres. Please tag the correct DBMS product name

Comment: Maybe because it's Paraccel, which was bought by Actian. I can't find any documentation on it. Thank you!

Comment: Tags and title updated. Thank you!